# Unable to start activity: SQLITE_ERROR (no such table: TABLE_NAME)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

**Background**:
I'm new to Android, I've a database in the assets folder and the user is supposed to be able to search that database from the action bar.
I don't create that database from the code itself, instead, when the app is launched for the first time, an empty database is created and my database gets copied to that empty database.
Right now, when I try to search the app craches due to the below error.
I've copied/edited the code from this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180528031737/https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

**Solutions tried**

1. I've went through answers on stackoverflow.com and from the comments
   section in the above link. it seems that most of those who managed
   to solve that error closed the database in different places in the
   code (db.close). I've tried placing a closing statement as commented
   in my code but in vain.
2. I know that one of the raised points is never to hardcode the path of the db, so I Checked that the table does exist!
3. Uninstalled, cleared cache, changed db version number. Still the same

**Error**:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.amgad.hayy/com.amgad.hayy.SearchableActivity}:
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: places (code
> 1): , while compiling: SELECT type, name FROM places WHERE _id=?

> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing
> database. (no such table: places (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT
> type, name FROM places WHERE _id=?)

**Complete LogCat**

> 11-20 10:52:35.231 28023-28023/com.amgad.hayy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.amgad.hayy, PID: 28023
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amgad.hayy/com.amgad.hayy.SearchableActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: places (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT type, name FROM places WHERE _id=?
> #################################################################
> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
> Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
> (no such table: places (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT type, name FROM places WHERE _id=?)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
> places (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT type, name FROM places
> WHERE _id=?
> #################################################################
> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
> Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
> (no such table: places (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT type, name FROM
> places WHERE _id=?)
> #################################################################
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
> Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1000)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:565)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1476)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1323)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1194)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1362)
> at com.amgad.hayy.data.HayyDbHelper.getAllEmployeesDescription(HayyDbHelper.java:228)
> at com.amgad.hayy.SearchableActivity.showPlaceName(SearchableActivity.java:52)
> at com.amgad.hayy.SearchableActivity.onCreate(SearchableActivity.java:44)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
> ... 9 more

**Code**

public class HayyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

> ```
> private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.amgad.hayy/databases/"; 
> static final String DB_NAME = "hayy.db";
> private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
> private final Context myContext;
> private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
>
>
> public static final String TABLE_NAME = "places";
> public static final String COLUMN_PLACE_ID = "_id";
> public static final String COLUMN_MONUMENT_NUMBER = "monument_number";
> public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
> public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
>
> public HayyDbHelper(Context context) {
>     super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
>     this.myContext = context;
> }
>
>
> public void createDb() throws IOException{
>     boolean dbExists = checkDb();
>     //SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
>     if(dbExists){
>         //do nothing, db already exists
>     }else{
>
>         //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
>         //of the application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
>         //db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
>         //db_Read.close();
>         this.getReadableDatabase();
>         try{
>            // this.close();
>             copyDb();
>
>         }catch(IOException e){
>             throw new Error("Error copying database");
>         }
>     }
>     //this.close();
> }
>
>
> private boolean checkDb(){
>
>     File databasePath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
>     return databasePath.exists();
>
> }
>
>
> private void copyDb() throws IOException{
>
>     //Open your local db as the input stream
>     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
>
>     //Path to the just created empty db
>     String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
>
>     //Open the empty db as the output stream
>     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
>
>
>     //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
>     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
>     int length;
>     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
>         myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
>     }
>
>     //Close the streams
>     myOutput.flush();
>     myOutput.close();
>     myInput.close();
> }
>
> public void openDb() throws SQLException {
>
>     //Open the database
>     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
>     myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public synchronized void close() {
>
>     if(myDataBase != null)
>         myDataBase.close();
>
>     super.close();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
>     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
>     onCreate(db);
> }
>
> public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
>     onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
> }
>
> public ArrayList<String> getAllName() {
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     ArrayList<String> pNames = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
>
>     if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
>         cursor.moveToFirst();
>
>
>         do {
>             String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
>
>             pNames.add(name);
>
>         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
>
>     }
>
>     cursor.close();
>     db.close();
>
>     return pNames;
> }
>
>
> public Cursor getAllEmployeesDescription(int id) {
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     String[] selections = {String.valueOf(id)};
>     String columns[] = {COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME};
>
>     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COLUMN_PLACE_ID + "=?",
>             selections, null, null, null);
>     //db.close();
>     return cursor;
> }
> ```

Main Method

> ```
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     myDatabaseHelper = new HayyDbHelper(MainActivity.this);
>
>     try {
>         myDatabaseHelper.createDb();
>
>     } catch (IOException ioe) {
>
>         throw new Error("Unable to create database");
>
>     }
>
>     try {
>         myDatabaseHelper.openDb();
>
>     }catch(SQLException sqle){
>
>         throw sqle;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Why the mysql tag? And just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: @CL.tags edited. Looking into your recommendation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have done. If you are using multiple tables and after running app using the SQLiteHandler you have created some tables and after that you tried to create one more table, than the problem is that the onCreate in the SQLiteHandler is called only once. Try to uninstall the app from the testing device (emulator/phone) and reinstall it.

Comment: No, nothing in the database is added/removed. I've also tried to uninstall/install, in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "GroceryCart.db";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,WEIGHT TEXT,COST TEXT,QUANTITY TEXT,IMAGE TEXT,USER_ID TEXT)");

        final String SQL_CREATE_GROCERYLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+
                <Table Name>+" ("+
                <Column Name>+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
               <Column Name>+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                <Column Name>+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                ");";

       
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_GROCERYLIST_TABLE);
      
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+GroceryEntry.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Then intialize it in your class like

```
        SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Now do the required operations using the mDatabase object.